# LSTM returns a sequence of probabilities with a Sigmoid Activation

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am new to LSTM's, so I tried writing a simple Sentiment Classification script in Keras. However, I am unable to make sense of the output.

Here is my Sentiment Classifier code :

```
    import keras
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, LSTM, Embedding

    from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
    ckpt = ModelCheckpoint('weights.hdf5', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, monitor='val_accuracy')

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(3200,128))
    model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(features,target, validation_split=0.2, epochs=ep, batch_size=bs, callbacks=[es, ckpt])
```

And here is my Sentiment Prediction Code:

```
def predict_on_test_sentences(model,sent):

    from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
    from keras.preprocessing import sequence

    t = Tokenizer()
    t.fit_on_texts(sent)
    test_converted = t.texts_to_sequences(sent)

    padded_text = sequence.pad_sequences(test_converted, padding='post', maxlen=32)

    assert padded_text.shape[1] == 32  

    y_prob = model.predict(padded_text)
    y_class = y_prob.argmax(axis=-1)

    print("Probabilities :\n{}\nClass : {}".format(y_prob, y_class))
    print(len(y_classes), len(y_prob))
```

My processed test sentence and model :

```
predict_on_test_sentences(model,"I absolutely love the food here. The service is great")
```

Finally, this is my output:

```
Probabilities :
[[0.05458272]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.01066688]
 [0.00394785]
 [0.08322579]
 [0.9882582 ]
 [0.8437737 ]
 [0.02924034]
 [0.1741887 ]
 [0.00972039]
 [0.8437737 ]
 [0.9607595 ]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.8437737 ]
 [0.9882582 ]
 [0.69985855]
 [0.00972039]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.1741887 ]
 [0.0162347 ]
 [0.00972039]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.01420724]
 [0.9882582 ]
 [0.9882582 ]
 [0.02542651]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.0162347 ]
 [0.00972039]
 [0.05820051]
 [0.00972039]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.1741887 ]
 [0.0162347 ]
 [0.00972039]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.08322579]
 [0.00972039]
 [0.05820051]
 [0.69985855]
 [0.05458272]
 [0.92422444]
 [0.00972039]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.05458272]
 [0.08322579]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.9990741 ]
 [0.05820051]
 [0.00972039]
 [0.01066688]
 [0.17418873]]
Class : [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
53 53
```

Can anyone help make sense of the output? What steps do I take next so that I can classify a given review as 0/1 (Negative/Positive)?
And an explanation of what I am doing wrong / what I can improve would be great too, thanks!

Comment: I am using [this](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Sentiment+Labelled+Sentences)  dataset. Using the amazon_cells_labelled.txt file for Sentiments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Sigmoid output

You're doing binary classification with your layer `Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")`.

With a sigmoid activation, your output is a single number between 0 and 1 which you can interpret as the probability of your first class. Observations with output close to 0 are predicted to be from the first class and those with output close to 1 from the second class.

The cut-off point need not be 0.5 (cf ROC curves) but it is a sensible value when interpreting the output as a probability since `P(class2) = 1 - P(class1)`.

Contrary to what another answer says, there is no need to use `Dense(2, activation = "softmax")` for binary classification. Your approach is better.

However, you don't make predictions with argmax with a sigmoid activated output. `argmax` of a single value is always 0. You want to compare the probability with your cut-off point instead, typically `0.5`.

For example, looking at your first 7 sentences:

```
[[0.05458272]
 [0.03890216]
 [0.01066688]
 [0.00394785]
 [0.08322579]
 [0.9882582 ]
 [0.8437737 ]]
```

The predicted classes are `[0 0 0 0 0 1 1]`.

Of course, your problem is that you didn't ask for so many sentences, only for one. The problem is...

### `texts` should be a list of sentences

`XXX_texts` functions expect a list of sentences. When you pass a single sentence, it is treated as a list of single characters.

Right now, you get a sequence and a prediction for each letter!

Change `test_converted = t.texts_to_sequences(sent)` to `test_converted = t.texts_to_sequences([sent])` and you're good.

Remember, it is `text*s*_to_sequence*s*`, not `text_to_sequence`!

### Tokenizer

Additionally, you need to use the training tokenizer on your test data! Otherwise, the tokens are different and you will get non-sensical results.

For example, your training tokenizer might encode "movie" as token 123 but, for your test tokenizer, token 123 could be "actor". If you don't use the same word index, the test sentences become gibberish to your model.

Comment: I'm using the same tokenizer on the test data. Should I use the same instance? It should not change much, since I tokenized my training set in the same fashion...

Comment: Also, I would still end up getting probabilities of n different classes, right? How do I say that the review on a whole is positive / negative, since I do not have one absolute value to take inference from? Thanks for the argmax explanation!

Comment: Yes, you should use the same tokenizer instance or rebuild the tokenizer with the same training data. A tokenizer builds an internal word index based on the word encountered and their frequency in the training data. Your "test" tokenizer will not have the same word index and the tokens will be different, resulting in non-sensical sentences for the point of view of the model.

Comment: With a sigmoid, you get only one probability `P(class1)`. You only need 1 since `P(class2) = 1 - P(class1)` in a binary context. This is why `Dense(2, activation = "softmax")` is redundant: the class probabilities only have 1 degree of freedom since they sum to 1.

Comment: @AamirSyed I just realized you were passing a single sentence yet getting many outputs. This is because you should use a list of sentences. See my edit.

Comment: I do not know how I did _not_ notice this. Thank you so much! It makes much more sense now. Also about the training tokenizer... would it make sense if i binarized or stored it as a pickle? So I can call and use it whenever I Need it for the test set? I try to modularize my code as much as possible, so I try to keep training and testing files separate. Thanks for the input and the edits on the code!

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are using word embedding. To get your output, use:

```
model.predict(padded_text)[0]
```

However, for classification purposes, you should go for an output shape of `(2,)` and use a softmax activation so that you would output a vector of certainties about your input being positive or negative. Then, an argmax on this output vector would yield the class your network thinks the input belongs to.

Comment: Why do I need a (2,) layer? And softmax??? Isn't softmax only useful when you have multiple classes? I want a simple binary classification, and from what I have learnt it is better to use sigmoid.... Do correct me if I am wrong though, I just cant seem to get the intuition behind using softmax for a binary classification. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you do have two classes: positive and negative. However, your approach should work.

Comment: Okay, but what is the intuition behind `model.predict(padded_text)[0]` ? That would just give me the probability value of the _first_ vector in the sequence of _n_ vectors, right? What are those _n_ vectors anyway? Because I get a different number of `y_classes` and `y_prob` values if I change the test sentence. Thanks for sharing knowledge!